# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type:>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to return a row from my DB but I get the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<< anonymous type: int Id, string File, string Name>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List< PDF.Models.EF_Model.PDF>'

This is in my model layer and in return statement is where error occurred

```
internal List<EF_Model.PDF> Search_PDF(string _name)
{
    using (var Context = new EF_Model.CoolerEntities())
    {
        var p = (from c in Context.PDFs
                 where c.Name == _name
                 select new { c.Id, c.File, c.Name }).Single();
        return p;
    }
}
```

And I also tried to put `ToList()`  instead of `Single()` but it wont work either,How can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method expects to return `EF_Model.PDF` but your linq query instantiates an anonymous type.

Instead instantiate the `PDF` type:

```
return from c in Context.PDFs
       where c.Name == _name
       select c;
```

Or:

```
internal List<EF_Model.PDF> Search_PDF(string _name)
{
    using (var Context = new EF_Model.CoolerEntities())
    {
        return Context.PDFs.Where(c => c.Name == _name).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: my bad sorry,i need a collection

Comment: @NeverTrust - then why did you add the `Single`? Do you expect to get many items or do you want only one?

Comment: I expect these Id, Name ,File

Comment: @NeverTrust - but do you expect a single `PDF` object or many

Comment: got this error when tried this ` return Context.PDFs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == _name);
` ..  >Cannot implicitly convert type 'PDF.Models.EF_Model.PDF' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PDF.Models.EF_Model.PDF>'

Comment: many object ...

Comment: @NeverTrust - see update

Comment: tnx in advanced,i'll mark your answer in 5 min(after the site let me to do it)